# Kubernetes - Send messages from service to all pods at once (broadcast)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

Is it possible to send information from a single service to **all pods** in the same cluster **at once**?

Currently I have a service that transfers messages one by one (Round-Robin). I need a way for it to send all in parallel, multicast.

Thanks.

Comment: Does using a headless service and iterating over returned list of IPs to send requests satisfy your requirement?

Comment: @AliTou Well, I think it is kind of workaround. Iterating over list of IPs is still going one by one. I don't see the solution for simultaneously transferring messages. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Send a packet with destination mac addres set to FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF

Comment: Yes, but you can send them asynchronously and have more control over them than relying on Kubernetes Service load balancing. Think of it as a way to create as many threads as the number of pods, then call them concurrently. I'm just thinking out loud.

Comment: I read on Red Hat site: "If you are using the OVN-Kubernetes default Container Network Interface (CNI) network provider, you can enable multicast on a per-project basis." But not sure wether it forces me to use OCP.
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.4/networking/ovn_kubernetes_network_provider/enabling-multicast.html